# How can i find the outermost lines in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am making a script that gets data from blueprint like images and puts that data inside a JSON file. Right now I need a way to get the dimension of the blueprint and those are the outermost lines. So I need to get the location of only those lines and then get the text from those lines. [image: marked lines]

I have marked the lines and text of what I need. Right now I already have a way to get the text with the coordinates but I still need a way to find the outermost lines only so I don't get the wrong sizes.

Comment: write 4 loops that all approach from 4 directions (north, east south west), once you reach the first line, you can break that particular loop...

Comment: Can you show the code of getting 'the text with coordinates'? Which coordinates do you get? Is it the location of the text or the location and size of the lines? If you have the location of the lines already, you need to find the maximum/minimum to get the boundaries.